# Performance Comparison: Check and set a flag Vs. Just set the flag

Tags: c#, performance

I have a dictionary of flags and by each event, I set the associated flag. Some events are from same type and have same id, so it's possible to set their flags multiple times. Would it be more fast, if I check a flag before setting it?

```
Dictionary<int, bool> flags = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach(var eventType in eventTypes)
{
    flags.Add(eventType.id, false);
}
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    // resetting flags for current iteration.
    foreach(var k in flags.Keys)
    {
        flags[k] = false;
    }
    Event[] events = GetEvents();
    foreach(var e in events)
    {
        flags[e.id] = True; // Would it be better to check flag before set it?
    }
    // Do related works for events occurred 
}
```

Comment: Why/for what would you want to check the flag for?

Comment: @chrfin To avoid setting a flag before was set. Events can have same id.

Comment: You mean to only set it to `false` if it is not already `false`?

Comment: To me if you're checking prior to setting you will have 2 operations to complete. A check and then a set. If you just set the flag you'll only have one. Worst case you'll have O(2n) if all flags need to be changed. If you have no check, it will always be O(n).

Comment: @Bmo But does test and take equal times?

Comment: @chrfin set it to `True` if it is not already `True`. Elements in `events` may have same `id`.

Comment: How often will they have same type and id? impossible to answer without today info

Comment: @SAM you can select distinct ids to avoid multiple lookup in dictionary `GetEvents().Select(e => e.id).Distinct()`

Comment: You could return a  `Dictionary<int, List<Event>>`  from `GetEvents` instead where the key is the event-id. Then you only need to enumerate the keys  and not the lists. By the way, why do you use that method in the loop and not before the loop?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's not possible for me to do that.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Your suggestion seems interesting to me. Would you provide an answer please?

Comment: @Sergey: I doubt this would yield any performance improvements since it needs to create an additional hashtable under the hood anyway.

Comment: Why do you keep `false` entries in the dictionary at all? You should create an empty dictionary, and only store keys which you got from `GetEvents()`. You can easily check if the dictionary contains an entry or not. In other words, you can simply write it in a single line: `var flags = GetEvents().ToLookup(e => e.Id);`.

Comment: @SAM: but you are building it. First you create a `new` instance. Then, you add values for all known event types. Then you iterate them again, and again set them to false. And finally, you use the `GetEvents` list to set some of them to true. I am pretty sure you only need the last step. If these lists are huge, and performance really matters to the nanosecond, then profile. What probably matters the most, it would may your code way more readable IMHO.

Comment: @Groo Would you update your answer with related code?

Comment: @SAM: sure, just a moment.

Comment: @Groo that depends on data in collections. Assume you have many duplicated events. Btw `Disctinct` uses `Set<T>`

Comment: @Sergey: that's C# we're talking about? You meant to say `HashSet<T>`>? Yes, but number of hashtable operations would remain the same in both cases if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @SAM: actually, it's more or less what Sergey wrote above. I.e. `new HashSet<string>(GetEvents().Select(e => e.Id));`. In that case, you would simply use `flags.Contains(someId)` to check if an event occurred.

Comment: @Groo yes, that's a C#. I you would go a level deeper, you will find [`Set<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#9c10b234c0932864#references) its funny to see your edit :)

Comment: @Sergey: crap, I haven't looked at the source. It's weird they didn't choose to reuse the existing class, cause it seems like a pretty similar implementation. Sorry, I didn't understand your first comment and didn't meant to steal the idea. I thought your comment meant that OP should filter events just before the last foreach. I only realized it's the same thing after SAM told me to update my answer and I actually started typing it. By all means, you should add this as your answer.

Comment: @Groo it's no problem - answer was helpful to OP and its good. No need to duplicate something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation which is the most expensive in this case happens when you index the dictionary. Whenever you try to add, update or read a value for a specific key, `Dictionary` needs to compute the hash value of your key, then get the appropriate bucket, and then iterate through elements in that bucket (if there are more than one doe to hash collisions) and compare them to the key.

If you checked the value before updating it, you would need to do this twice, in case that you need to change the value.

On a side note, this is exactly why [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the preferred (more performant) method for getting a value which may or may not be in the dictionary: because calling `ContainsKey` and then indexing the dictionary would take two operations (or, even worse, catching the `KeyNotFoundException`).

Also, if the range of your `int` keys is limited, you may consider using a [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `Dictionary`.

**[Edit]**

Presumably, you use the dictionary to check if a given event occurred at least once. To do this, you can simply write:

```
var eventIds = new HashSet<string>(GetEvents().Select(e => e.Id));
```

To check if an event occurred efficiently, you would query the hashset:

```
if (eventIds.Contains(id))
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In any Dictionary based operation, lookup time is likely to far surpass the time needed to set a flag, which typically will involve simply setting a single value in memory.

If you just set the flag without checking, then that involves only one lookup.

If you check first, then this potentially involves two lookups. However it's quite likely that the compiler will optimize this down to just a single lookup, so the speed may be similar.

Conclusion:

- Not checking is potentially faster, but this will only be noticeable if the compiler isn't good at optimzation
- If you're really concerned about performance, consider whether you can use arrays instead of dictionaries in your application, since arrays tend to be faster.

However that's just based on my knowledge and instincts. If you're really serious about performance, then the only real solution is to write some code to test how fast various approaches are!

Answer (score 1):

Only setting the flags to `false` if they are `true` is slower, because you would need to query the dictionary twice.
If you set the flag directly it is only one operation.

Additionaly you would also need to prevent race-conditions if you have a multi-threaded environment by e.g. putting a `lock` around the "check&set" logic which would slow it down even more.

The only reason for doing a check I can think of would be if you have a custom dictionary which does trigger something on a set event even if it is the same value and you want to avoid that.